# How to add Jquery in mytemplate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I try to insert a jquery script for an item in my theme .I created a custom theme for Wordpress but I need that script to run as I want.

My theme contains the following

1.header.php

2.index.php (Here are the elements to which they want to apply the script)

3.footer.php

4.style.css

In ../mytemplate/js i added this file jquery-1.4.2.min.js

The script which l we found uses this thing, so m-I thought they must to a I add and I.

You must create a new file that myscript.js to add all the mytemplate / js?

In header.php ... you must add a reference link to my script

The best thing would help me a tutorial or an example that explains in detail all these steps.
Can you help me with any ideas or advice?

This is Jquery script:

http://usingjquery.com/2010/10/using-jquery-to-create-a-drop-down-div/

This is a demo:

http://usingjquery.com/tutorials/using_jquery_to_make_a_drop_down_box/

Answer (score 0):

First you have to load all your scripts properly, and you do so by loading them on functions.php using "`wp_enqueue_scripts`" hook

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'um_enq_scripts_styles' );
function um_enq_scripts_styles(){
  wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
  wp_enqueue_script( 'script',get_template_directory_uri()."/assets/js/script.js",null,"1.0",true);
}
```

You you have to **enqueue** only the **jQuery** handle, as it is registered by WordPress previously, and on the second one you can see how to register and enqueue your own script where you can type **jQuery** code.

On the script where you type jQuery code you have to use jQuery or you can pass $ on document ready event as jQuery is registered with no conflict mode and **$** does not reference jQuery in order to prevent interfering with other libraries

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//Your jQuery Code
});
```

And don't forget to call `wp_footer()` and `wp_header()` in order to print all those scripts and styles on your template.